# How do I link to a specific page of a PDF document inside a cell in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pdf, xlsxwriter

I am writing a python code which writes a hyperlink into a excel file.This hyperlink should open in a specific page in a pdf document.

I am trying something like
Worksheet.write_url('A1',"C:/Users/...../mypdf#page=3") but this doesn't work.Please let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to open the pdf file directly to a specific page even without xlsxwriter? I can not.

From Adobe's official site:

> To target an HTML link to a specific page in a PDF file, add
>   #page=[page number] to the end of the link's URL.
>
> For example, this HTML tag opens page 4 of a PDF file named
>   myfile.pdf:
>
> Note: If you use UNC server locations (\servername\folder) in a link,
>   set the link to open to a set destination using the procedure in the
>   following section.
>
> ## If you use URLs containing local hard drive addresses (c:\folder), you cannot link to page numbers or set destinations.